# Is there a way to automatically get the gradient along the different dimensions of an array?

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, derivative

I am trying to find a way to automate the computation of the gradient of a function along its different dimensions, in Matlab.

I have found the gradient function [here](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gradient.html), but it requires me to write down individual output variables for each dimensions.
Since I am calculating gradients in the middle of a sampling algorithm, I want the gradient calculation to automatically scale with higher dimensional input.

Basically, if `F` is a vector, I would want:
`G = gradient(F)`
to be a cell array with a single entry: a vector with all the gradient values.
However, if `F` is 2D-array, I would like `G` to be a cell array with entries `GX` and `GY`, where `GX` is the gradient along the X direction and `GY` the gradient along the Y direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would do the trick:

```
nd = sum(size(F)>1);
G = cell(nd,1);
[G{:}] = gradient(F);
```

`nd` is the number of dimensions (simply calling `ndims` is not suitable, since a vector has 2 dimensions in MATLAB, everything has at least 2 dimensions). The `[G{:}]` construct assigns one output argument of `gradient` to each of the elements of the cell array.

Comment: Does the job! Thanks for answer and the feedback on the formulation!